# draw.io - objects adjust their distances automatically

Tags: draw.io

I want to use Draw.io to draw a WBS chart. The chart has too many nodes and each parent node can have multiple children. I wanted to know if there is any way in Draw.io, so that when a new child is added, it's distance with siblings be updated automatically?I dont want the children to collide and I always want them to be separate and have distance.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the Draw.io CRM, and they told me its not possible for nodes to be relocated automatically. But I can use advanced container shapes for WBS and org charts and flow charts that do auto-layouts.

Here is a helpful blog post for it:
[automated-layout-shapes](https://www.diagrams.net/blog/automated-layout-shapes)